# Fabric beta manual distribution sometime does not send invitation email

Tags: google-fabric, fabric-beta

The Fabric beta manual distribution sometime does not send invitation email even in the webpage it show "Invited" to the person. If I click resend invitation, that person will get it. My QA team people has to come to me all the time for resend the invitation. I know Fabric team always around here so My question is : Is it a known issue and Do you have solution or workaround for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Invitations are sent once per tester per app. If a tester doesn't accept the original email, then additional invites will only be sent if you resend the invite to them and they won't receive notices of new builds since they're not testing the app.

Comment: Thx Mike, I know you are always around here.  one more question, Do we send invitation to for each version of an app?

Comment: :) Invitations are only sent when the user is first invited. Notifications for each new distribution can be enabled or disabled. The configuration name depends on how you're distributing.

Comment: If you are Android Studio how do you do it and the same for the OSX Fabric distribution for iOS apps. Thanks.

Comment: @RickR I'm not following your question. We don't support macOS app distribution.

Comment: Currently experience same bug. When person invited email not arrived. Checked with few email addresses. Email sent only after 'resend'.

Comment: I think it is not a bug but an unexpected case. it is hard to tell whether user click on the mail or not receive it.

Comment: Yeah, the emails are very flaky.  I had issues with initial emails and resent emails getting received.  I would just invite them and resend the invite several times if you want to at least be somewhat sure the emails get sent.

Answer (score 1):

Beacause if tester doesn't accept the first invite email, the next invite emails will not be sent.

Trick for resent invitation: if tester's email is gmail, add surffix to tester's email, ex:

tester@gmail.com -> tester+1@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Invites are sent once per tester app as Mike mentioned above. If a tester does not accept the initial invite or had unsubscribed then tester will not receive the email, but the developer can resend an invitation in the Beta dashboard (see beat dashboard image) and the tester should get that invite. If tester still not getting the invite then reach out to Fabric support (to unblock/re-subscribe the tester) or ask developer to resubscribe from the initial/first invite.[Beta dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xpyw.png)